# concat lines from several .txt file using python?

Tags: python

Im using python 3.6 on windows 10, i have a task to take data from 1.txt and concat them with some string and put the results on 2.txt file .

this is my code:

```
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

#file read from
pic_name = open("test.txt","r")
#file write to it 
full_name = open("full_name.txt","a")
while True:
    line = pic_name.readline()
    link = line+full_url
    print(link)
    full_name.write(link)
    if ("" == line):
        print("file finished")
        break;
pic_name.close()
full_name.close()
```

after executing the code it gives me this result:

> ```
> p100003.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100026.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100951.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100970.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p101144.jpghttps://mysite/images/pic_person/small/https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/
> ```

and except results will be like this :

> ```
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100026.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100951.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100970.jpg
> https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p101144.jpg
> ```

the file test.txt contains these lines :

```
p100026.jpg
p100951.jpg
p100970.jpg
p101144.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to append file on the bottom you need to use 'a' flag in the open file and put "\n" as enter

```
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

# file read from test.txt
f = open("test.txt", "r")

# iterating each file on pict and write it
with open("text2.txt", "a") as file_object:
    for item in f:
        file_object.write(full_url+item.splitlines()[0]+"\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: @Insight Habor `file_object.write(full_url+item)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the line

```
full_name.write(link)
```

with

```
full_name.writeline(link)
```

Alternativly  you can write a "new line character" yourself (think of it as simulating pressing enter)

```
full_name.write(link + '\r\n')
```

Comment: are you running your code ? because its not working and gives me new errors man! .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

with open("test.txt") as pic_name:
    links = [full_url + line.rstrip() for line in pic_name]
    
    with open("full_name.txt","w") as name:
        name.write("\n".join(links))
```

**or**

```
with open("test.txt") as pic_name:
    with open("full_name.txt","a") as name:
        for line in pic_name:
            name.write(full_url + line.rstrip() + "\n")
```

**Output in `full_name.txt`**

```
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100026.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100951.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100970.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p101144.jpg
```

Comment: This consumes too much memory if the file is big. Use the `for` loop like in my example, then the memory footprint stays small.

Answer (score 0):

- Prefer `with open(file, mode=["r", "w", "w+"]) as <file_handler>:` over `open()` and `<fhandler>.close()`. In case an error occurs, the file stream gets closed automatically in the `with` version while not in the latter version. So `with` is much safer and robust.
- Use `for` loop over the file handler - then no explicit test for end of file (`eof`) is needed. And it reads line by line. Your test with `line == ""` might be okay for this case - but it might not be okay for another case. Using the for-loop is the more universal solution. In addition - and more importantly - the memory is occupied only by one line of the `fin` file at any time point. So memory footprint stays small.

So the most pythonic way for this problem is:

```
infile = "test.txt"
outfile = "full_name.txt"
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

with open(infile, "r") as fin:
    with open(outfile, "a") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(full_url + line + "\n")
            # or: print(full_url + line, end="\n", file=fout)
```

If you want the verbose printing out like in your example, do:

```
infile = "test.txt"
outfile = "full_name.txt"
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

with open(infile, "r") as fin:
    with open(outfile, "a") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            result_line = full_url + line
            print(result_line, end="\n", file=fout)
            print(result_line)
print("file finished")
```

Comment: If you run your code you will notice that the `writeline` attribute does not exist I think you mean `writelines` to store a list

Comment: @HSNHK Ah thank you - I jump between languages - and I thought writeline exists - I should have tested it in ipython :D . That is stupid that Python does not have `.writeline()`. One should ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
full_url = "https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/"

outfile = "fullname.txt"
infile = "test.txt"

with open(outfile, "a") as w:
    with open(infile, "r") as r:
        for line in r:  # read each line in the input file
            w.write(f"{full_url}{line}")  # write to output file
```

##### Input file, test.txt

```
p100026.jpg
p100951.jpg
p100970.jpg
p101144.jpg
```

##### Output file fullname.txt

```
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100026.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100951.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p100970.jpg
https://mysite/images/pic_person/small/p101144.jpg
```